# Run external application using Django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a django backend. In it I want to run an external Python application I wrote, when someone clicks a button.
My project is distributed as follows:

```
external_application_folder
main_django_project_folder
django_app_folder
```

The way I am currently doing it is, I have created a `html file` which has a form in it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            ABM TRY
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="run_external_code"> Run</button>
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Inside the `django_app's` `views.py` I have

```
from external_application_folder.run import external_function
def ex_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST' and 'run_external_code' in request.POST:
        external_function()
    return render(request,"html_file.html",{})
```

whenever I run `python manage.py runserver`
I get the following

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

and then everything works.

I am new to django, is this the best way to run external application using backend?

Answer (score 0):

`Watching for file changes with StatReloader` and `Performing system checks...` are merely debug informations provided by the `runserver` command. That command is by no means providing production-grade HTTP serving, though! Use it only for testing.

The method you provided *might* actually work, you need to pay attention to not allow malicious actors to be able to manipulate the DOM (that is, the HTML file and its content) to be capable of sending requests and thus running Python commands in your server that you don't want to happen.

As for running external Python code: you can write your own management commands like `runserver` that you can call even programmatically. [See Django management commands doc for more.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) I'd suggest this as the primary method for Python code execution as it's both versatile and very well isolated, and thus, largely safe. Definitely depends on your code though!

You don't have to rely on Python code for tasks - shellscripts, Make targets, JS execution, remote HTTP calls, or even RPCs are all valid, actually - but your question is a bit vague and a lot of factors are can be taken into consideration, such as security, separation of concerns and scalability.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check out Django management commands.